# Why does my router link sent me back to the default home page instead of going to the page I want?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This started just recently, but basically what happens is that I start my site in a LandingPage which has the path --> ":#/" On that page I have a button that sends me to my login page with the path --> ":#/login" or to a page to register a new account, with the path -->":#/register".

On my login Page I have a navBar that allows me to change from the login page to my landingPage. And the login page has a button that takes me to the register page.

When I enter my register page I can finish the registry and I go back to my login page, as intended, by clicking the button to submit. At the same time, in this registry page, I have access to the same navBar.

The navbar has a link to the landingPage and to loginPage. The issue is, when I click to go to login, instead of having the path ":#/login", I have the path ":login#/" and I'm sent back to my landingPage.

At this point, if I try to login again I go to ":login#/login". I can't really understand why, since this was not happening before.

html ------

```
 <b-collapse type="dark" id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
    <b-navbar-nav>
      <b-nav-item to="/">LandingPage</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
    <b-navbar-nav>
      <b-nav-item to="/login">Login</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
```

vue-router-----------

```
  const routes = [
```

{
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "register",
    component: Register
  },

{
    path: "/",
    name: "landingPage",
    component: LandingPage
  },
]

Comment: Can we see the code you used to set up your vue-router and the line that is causing the url to prepend `:login`?

Comment: yes, please show as your router

Comment: @PiotrMirosz I added the code

Comment: @jacob13smith I added the code